# Blazor Web Assembly, FIDO2 and Identity Server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, openid-connect, identity

Is it possible to integrate FIDO2 WebAuthn with Blazor Web Assembly authorization and Identity Server? I am able to use FIDO2 to log in directly to Identity, but I cannot see how to use FIDO2 with my Blazor OIDC connection logic.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I have gotten everything working well. Basically I use the ASP.NET Core Identity pages - login, Enable2FA, etc. - to manage the registration and login processes. The final step in the login process, once the FIDO2 biometric login has completed successfully, is to from within the FIDO2 controller MakeAssertion call complete the sign-on with SignInManager's SignInAsync.

Biometric login is now working well from iOS, Android, Windows Hello, and using a Yubikey security key.

Comment: What library/ package are you using to handle the biometric login process? Did you find code examples?

Comment: If possible, can you put the non-proprietery part of your code onto GitHub and share with the wider community here?